# Nuxt.js document is not defined (vuejs-datepicker)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datepicker, nuxt.js

---

***i did all thing (maybe) to solve this problem but my little error keep coming out....:(***

---

**First. my error-**
my "vuejs-datepicker" work well when load page first time.
BUT when i reload it, "Reference Error" show up...
[my error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4LHQ.png)

---

**Second. what i did-**

- add /plugins/vuejs-datepicker file

  ```
  import Vue from 'vue';
  import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker';

  Vue.use(Datepicker);
  ```
- add `plugins : [{ src: '~plugins/vuejs-datepicker', ssr: false }]` in nuxt.config.js
- use `client-only` in template

  `<client-only>
    <datepicker :inline="true"></datepicker>
  </client-only>`

---

**Third. even did this-**

- in /plugins/vuejs-datepicker file,
  change `Vue.use(Datepicker)` to `Vue.component('vuejs-datepicker',DatePicker)`
- in script of vue, 
   
  change `components: {datepicker}` 
  to `components: {'datepicker': () => import('vuejs-datepicker')},`

---

so, what else should i do now??
Any ideas?
Thanks..

Answer (score 9):

You were almost there!

It means that vuejs-datepicker doesn't work on SSR.

I faced the same issue and Following [this guide](https://aslamdoctor.com/blog/using-vuejs-datepicker-with-nuxt-js/226) I could resolve the problem.

- First of all you must install the component

  ```
  npm i vuejs-datepicker
  ```
- Secondly, you need to create a plugin file, under `plugins` directory, for instance: `vue-datepicker.js` with the following content:

  ```
  import Vue from 'vue'
  import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker'
  Vue.component('date-picker', Datepicker)
  ```

  In this step you are registering as `date-picker` in the context your component, imported from `vuejs-datepicker`, this name is important because is the one you will use insted of the original `datepicker`.
- Next step is register your new plugin in `nuxt.config.js`

  ```
  plugins : [
            ...OthersPlugins,
             { src: '~/plugins/vue-datepicker', mode: 'client' }
            ]
  ```

  In this way you will be using this component only from the client side.
- The final step is enjoy your Datepicker as `date-picker` in your component or page, but now with the name used in the Second Step

  ```
  <date-picker ..options/>
  ```

  You don't need to import anything in the component, this `date-picker` now is available on every component or page in the project as it.
- The very Last step, which is optional is to wrap this date-picker with `client-only` tag, if you want to show any message while the date-picker is loading.

For more info about this please read:

- [configuration-plugins](https://nuxtjs.org/guides/configuration-glossary/configuration-plugins)
- [components-client-only](https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-client-only/)

Comment: Couldn't get this to work until I removed the import statement as you recommended, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It means vuejs-datepicker dont work on SSR. You need to use it only on client. See https://nuxtjs.org/api/components-client-only/ and  https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/#client-side-only

Answer (score 0):

```
//plugin.js   
 import Vue from 'vue';
 import Datepicker from 'vuejs-datepicker';    
 Vue.use(Datepicker);

//nuxt.config.js

plugins : [
           { src: '~/plugins/plugin.js', ssr: false},
          ] 

//usage

<div>
<client-only>
<Datepicker />    
</client-only>

</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.